# Iterate over all elements of a hazelcast datastructure (for example IMap) without loading them into memory at once

Tags: java, hazelcast

I want to retrieve all values of a hazelcast IMap - like with IMap#values(). Looking at the sourcecode it seems that all elements are loaded into memory of the caller:

```
public Collection<V> values() {
    Collection<Data> dataSet = valuesInternal();
    Collection<V> valueSet = new ArrayList<V>();
    for (Data data : dataSet) {
        valueSet.add((V) getService().toObject(data));
    }
    return valueSet;
}
```

What is the best way to iterate over all elements?

Jan

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to do?

And we are going to change the implementations so that not the whole collection will be pulled in memory, but more like a resultset you will get chunks of the data.

Comment: Hi, I read a large File, distribute the tree different record types to different nodes (using a MultiMap and IMap), calculate things using a DistributedExecutor and finally I want to retrieve all records back and write them to a file. A resultset (In the JDBC sence) sounds great! (Any chance to do it with the current stable release?)

Comment: It probably will be 3.3 or 3.4. We have a whole bunch of other things we need to do. But this is certainly on the list.

Comment: Good to hear, can't wait to have it. Any idea for a workaround in the current version?